# How to extract image links from sites?

Tags: images, extract, links

So I have been trying to extract links of images from some public boards then edit them to their max resolution and then save them.

The problem is page source code only gives links to 52 out of 540 (page is fully loaded).

'http://pinterest.com/halliejarrell17/quotes-of-life/'

I tried page info too on FF but nothing.

Answer (score -1):

It certainly can be done with FireFox. Just did it myself.

1. Open the page in FireFox
2. Right-click on the blank spot
3. Click on "View Page Info"
4. A dialog opens, click on Media tab:
   [image]
5. There is a list of all the images.
6. To save them simply select the first image in the list that is of interest. Then scroll the list down and Shift-Click on the last image of interest to select a whole bunch of links. Then click on Save as, and FireFox will do the rest.

2 possible sources of confusion:

- Not scrolling the list of media links and noticing that not all the items are displayed by default.
- Not scrolling the web page far enough down so that all desired images are loaded (because they are being loaded on demand).